# Computing a Fréchet derivative of a norm function including the Laplacian operator

Tags: banach-spaces, normed-spaces, laplacian, regularization, frechet-derivative

I am curious about the Fréchet derivative of a misfit regularization term, defined as follows: Let

$$
\phi(\mathbf{m}) = \frac{1}{2}||\nabla^2(\mathbf{m} - \mathbf{m}^{\textrm{ref}})||_2^2
$$
be said regularization term, where $\mathbf{m}\in\mathbb{R}^n = \mathbf{m}(\mathbf{x})$, $\mathbf{x}\in\mathbb{R}^n$, $\mathbf{m}^{\textrm{ref}}\in\mathbb{R}^n$ is constant, and

$$
\nabla^2 f(\mathbf{x}) \triangleq \sum_{i = 1}^n\frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial x_i^2},
$$
where $x_i$ denotes the $i$-th entry of the $\mathbf{x}$ $n$-th dimensional vector.

How can I compute the Fréchet derivative with respect to $\mathbf{m}$, which we can denote as $\nabla_m \phi(\mathbf{m})$?

I have researched the concept and the properties of Fréchet derivatives as generalized directional derivatives over Banach spaces. On preliminary efforts, I have been tempted to take the Laplacian operator as the bounded operator, such that, following [(Wikipedia)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fr%C3%A9chet_derivative), I conclude that
$$
\nabla_m \phi(\mathbf{m}) = \nabla^2(\mathbf{m} - \mathbf{m}^{\textrm{ref}}).
$$
However, works such as [(Grayver, 2013)](http://www.diss.fu-berlin.de/diss/servlets/MCRFileNodeServlet/FUDISS_derivate_000000013655/Grayver2013_PhDThesis_online.pdf) when introducing a discrete analog of $\mathbf{L}$ of $\nabla^2$ they compute $\nabla_m$---neglecting any relation to a Fréchet derivative---obtaining:

$$
\nabla_m \phi = \mathbf{L}^T\mathbf{L}(\mathbf{m} - \mathbf{m}^{\textrm{ref}}),
$$
which baffles me, since $\mathbf{L}^T\mathbf{L}$ is not a discrete analog for $\nabla^2$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Generally, one replaces $\mathbf m$ with $\mathbf m+\delta$ and then extracts the term that is linear in $\delta$. In this case, 
$$\frac{1}{2}\|\nabla^2(\mathbf{m} +\delta - \mathbf{m}^{\textrm{ref}})\|_2^2 
= \frac12\langle \nabla^2(\mathbf{m} +\delta - \mathbf{m}^{\textrm{ref}}), \nabla^2(\mathbf{m} +\delta - \mathbf{m}^{\textrm{ref}})\rangle $$
so the linear term is 
$$\langle \nabla^2 \delta, \nabla^2 (\mathbf{m} - \mathbf{m}^{\textrm{ref}}) \rangle $$
Under reasonable boundary conditions (such as vanishing at infinity), the Laplacian is self-adjoint, which allows us to move it to the other side, getting 
$$\langle  \delta, \nabla^4 (\mathbf{m} - \mathbf{m}^{\textrm{ref}}) \rangle$$ 
So, the Frechét derivative is the biLaplacian of $(\mathbf{m} - \mathbf{m}^{\textrm{ref}})$, or, more precisely, the linear functional indiced by it on $L^2$.